Playing sounds for a local player after they leave the game
I've been trying to make a script that plays a sound after a player has left the game in a way that they can still hear the sound themselves. As far as I'm concerned, the issue I've run into is that Roblox deletes the script way too fast for it to work. However, I've seen many horror games use such an effect. I'm wondering if there's a known bypass around this. Any help or input is appreciated.
The code I'm currently using:
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local sound = game.workspace.TestSound
local function playLeaveSound(player)
    sound.Parent = SoundService
    sound:Play()
end

Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(playLeaveSound)


You can't play any sounds after the player leaves your experience. Consider maybe playing the sound when the player opens the CoreGui menu when they try to leave instead?

https://devforum.roblox.com/t/how-to-detect-when-a-certain-player-is-leaving-the-game/1281902/12?u=batatiz_alt
A player instances parent should never change in normal circumstances. so if it does you can reliable say that the player left the game.
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local sound = game.workspace.TestSound
player:GetPropertyChangedSignal("Parent"):Connect(function()
local function playLeaveSound(player)
    sound.Parent = SoundService
    sound:Play()
end   
print("Destroying")
end)

